# Data scraping: How to check if a web page contains a specific string

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to create an "if statement" to check if the string "cette entreprise est membre de la FVE" is part of the a web page.

```
item_url = "http://www.fveconstruction.ch/anDetails.aspRT=2&M=01&R=1&ID=42105701"
response = requests.get(item_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
test = soup.findAll(text = re.compile('cette entreprise est membre de la FVE.\w+..\w+'))
print(test)
```

And it prints me an empty list. Is there someone with an idea? 
And I would like to know how to check the statement? If I write :

```
if soup.findAll(text = re.compile('cette entreprise est membre de la FVE.\w+..\w+')): 
     do smth
else:
     do smth
```

If there isn't the string I'm looking for, it supposed to return false right?

Comment: Why can't you just use `'text' in response.text`?

Comment: Yes, if `findAll` returns an empty list, it will be treated as false and the code will go to the `else`.

Comment: Before the edit, this post said ```.findAll()``` ... It's best to use ```.find_all()``` if you're using BS4 because findAll is from bs3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the HTML of the page you provided in your code and noticed two things.  Here is the actual HTML of the text you're trying to find:

```
<span class="entrepriseDef">Cette entreprise est membre de la FVE&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
```

The two problems I see in your code is that you're searching for a lower-case "c", not an upper case "C".  Also, you're searching for a period at the end of the text which isn't there.  When you're screen-scraping a website, view the HTML of that page (type Control+U in your browser to see the HTML) and search for the exact text.  Then copy/paste that text into your code so it is precise.

Your code should be like this:

```
item_url = "http://www.fveconstruction.ch/anDetails.asp?RT=2&M=01&R=1&ID=42105701"
response = requests.get(item_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
test = soup.findAll(text = re.compile('Cette entreprise est membre de la FVE\w+..\w+'))
print(test)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have no way of knowing if your `regex` works or not, as your regex is not part of your post.

This answer is to show you how to check if the "*webpage contains a specific string*", without the `regex` issue.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://www.fveconstruction.ch/anDetails.asp?
RT=2&M=01&R=1&ID=42105701')

if 'cette entreprise est membre de la FVE.' in r.text:
    print ('Yes')
else:
    print ('No')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but why It returns me "no" and it should return me "yes". Is there something special on the site ? If you look at the url, just below the bold title "A.GUIDO & FILS SA", it's written "Cette entreprise est membre de la FVE" ?

Comment: You have `cette` in your code and in your comment you wrote `Cette` with capital C. Also, there is a `.` period in your code that's not in your comment. Make sure that the `string` in your `if` statement is exactly the same as in the text.